# Is it possible to transfer fund from a bitcoin wallet to paypal?

Tags: wallet, paypal

If I have a bitcoin `wallet` and a `paypal` account, I want to transfer my money from the wallet to paypal ; is it possible ? If so how to do ?

Comment: I find the best way to answer this sort of question is to Google *PayPal bitcoin*

Answer (score 1):

According to PayPal's [cryptocurrency FAQ](https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/cryptocurrency-on-paypal-faq-faq4398), you cannot currently transfer bitcoin into or out of PayPal. You can only hold whatever you bought on PayPal.

Comment: So where should I transfer my Bitcoin in order to convert it to dollars for example ?